# Get a target's final list of COMPILE_DEFINITIONS

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a converter from CMake to a internal build system and I need to get the final list of properties used to build a target - the list that I can see in Visual Studio or Xcode.

For example `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` can be set on the target, on the directory where the target is defined or in any parent directory. To get the full list of `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` I must call both `get_target_property` and `get_directory_property` and maybe something else that I'm not aware of.

Is there a simple way to get the full `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` used to build the target?

Comment: If you go that path, you will also retrieve the public definitions from all libraries that your target depends on.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish with this, but perhaps the setting [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) may be something to take a look at...